# apply rolling custom function on a dataframe with multiple outputs

Tags: pandas, apply

I have the following dataframe: mydf

```
 Date        A       B      C
 1973-01-01  0.002 -0.003 0.004  
 1973-02-01  0.003 -0.005 0.006  
 ...
```

I have a function that takes dataframe, Date Field, type of covariance
and returns the average return, the covariance matrix, and the annualized covariance matrix

```
def myfunc(mydf, dtfield, typecov):

    #does some computations based on type either equal weighted or exponentially weighted 
    ...
    ...
    return eret, cov, covA
```

The call to myfunc(mydf, 'Date', 'e')

I am trying to use rolling function in pandas in order to do this, using a 250 window, but i am not sure how to do this.

it works when i use a for loop

minwindow = 250

```
for i in range(minwindow, minwindow+5):
    temp = mydf[i-minwindow:i]
    eret, c, cA = myfunc(temp,dtfield, typeCov)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your parameter datafield right put you could try mydf.rolling(250).apply(myfunc, args=(['A','B','C'],'equal_weighted'))

Comment: the date field is just to identify the date column in my dataframe

Comment: it works if i use a for loop but it takes way to much time